# Remove dot after entry title in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

My teacher has a very specific way he wants bibliographies to be done which is similar to APA, but with changes. To fully comply with what he wants, I need to remove the dot that is automatically inserted after the entry title in a @Inbook item. I am using the biblatex-apa style as it is already very close to what I need.

For example, I would like to get

Briones, C. (2014). Quasispecies In *Encyclopedia of Astrobiology*. Berlin: Springer Heidelberg.

As the output of in my bibliography. What I get using my entry linked bellow is
[image: Bibliography output]

I guess I have to use `\DeclareFieldFormat`, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work since even just trying to add text to it like such: `\DeclareFieldFormat[Inbook]{title}{Title: \mkbibemph{#1}}` does nothing.

This is my entry in my .bib. I know I used some hacks like adding the "In" to the `bookTitle` entry, but it was the simplest way I could find to get what I needed.

```
@Inbook{Briones2014Quasispecies,
author="Briones, Carlos",
title={Quasispecies},
bookTitle={\emph{In} {E}ncyclopedia of {A}strobiology},
year="2014",
publisher="Berlin: Springer Heidelberg",
}
```

M(N)WE: (Using the bib entry given earlier)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Encyclopedias.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    bibliography = {Bibliography},
    references = {Bibliography},
}

%Does not change anything to output:
\DeclareFieldFormat[Inbook]{title}{Title: \mkbibemph{#1}} 


\author{Natmath}
\date{\today}
\title{Research Paper Step 1}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \cite{Briones2014Quasispecies}


    \printbibliography
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: show a small but complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Ok, I added and example with the citation, style and entry. @UlrikeFischer, thanks

Comment: you need to use lowercase for the entry types, so something like this `\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\nopunct}\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{booktitle}{In \mkbibemph{#1}}`, but be aware that apa is complicated and imho it is better to leave it as it is.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. Would you mind writing it as an answer, and I'll accept it for further reference to others.

Comment: I know that this breaks APA standards, but I kinda have to do it because this teacher is super strict on his own variation of APA. Thank you still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use lowercase for the entry types. So to change title and booktitle in inbook do something like this:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\nopunct}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{booktitle}{In \mkbibemph{#1}}
```

Be aware that the apa style is complicated and that they can be side effects.