# How to get rid of the dot at the end of the title of a reference in beamer class?

Tags: beamer, biblatex

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,sorting=ynt,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true,sortcites=true,language=british,backref=true,url=false,doi=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\nopunct}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{uncharter_45}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

where the bibliographic entry is:

```
@misc{uncharter_45,
    title = {Charter of the United Nations},
    author = {{United Nations}},
    year = {1945},
    shorthand = {UN~Charter}
}
```

I want to get rid of the dot at the end of the title, because I need (Cit on p. 1) to start with a lowercase letter. **How can I get rid of the dot at the end of the title?** I have followed the suggestion of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/589125/remove-dot-after-entry-title-in-biblatex) by adding `\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\nopunct}`, but as shown in the MWE, it did not work.

Comment: I don't think the period comes from the title, but from one of the many empty fields in between the title and the backref. I'm sure once @moewe sees this question, you'll get a proper answer, but if you just want to get the `Cit.` in lower case, you could try this hack: `\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{pageref}{\nopunct}`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. After messing around a bit, I also think that the dot does not come from the title. What is curious is that the exact same bibliography settings in the `article` class correctly omit that dot. But in `beamer`, for some reason, it seems to be different...

Comment: Ok, the difference between article and beamer class seems to be caused by this patch used by beamer to get the correct colours `\apptocmd{\abx@macro@title}
       {\ifcsundef{abx@field@title}{}{\ifpunct{}{\midsentence\newunitpunct}}%
        \newblock\unspace\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}{}{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer patches a couple of biblatex macros to e.g. get the correct colours for the individual elements of the bibliography. Amongst others it uses this patch:

```
 \apptocmd{\abx@macro@title}
   {\ifcsundef{abx@field@title}{}{\ifpunct{}{\midsentence\newunitpunct}}%
    \newblock\unspace\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}}{}{}
```

which seems to cause the different behaviour between article and beamer class you observe.

You can undo the patches with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,sorting=ynt,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true,sortcites=true,language=british,backref=true,url=false,doi=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\nopunct}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=cyan}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{fg=green}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=orange}

\makeatletter
\let\oldmacrotitle\abx@macro@title
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\abx@macro@title\oldmacrotitle
\apptocmd{\blx@env@bibliography}
   {\let\makelabel\beamer@biblabeltemplate}{}{}
\apptocmd{\abx@macro@begentry}
   {\let\bbx@tempa\@empty%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\abx@macro@labeltitle}
   {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcsundef{abx@field@label}}
      and test {\ifcsundef{abx@field@labeltitle}} }{}{\let\bbx@tempa\labelnamepunct}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\abx@macro@title}
   {\ifcsundef{abx@name@labelname}{}{\let\bbx@tempa\labelnamepunct}%
    \bbx@tempa\newblock\unspace\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\abx@macro@title}
 {\ifcsundef{abx@field@title}{}{}%
  \newblock\unspace\usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}{}{}}    
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
\citet{uncharter_45}

\index{test}

\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I do want the correct colors in the bibliography.

Comment: @Hector Please see my edited answer.

Comment: This warning has nothing to do with this patch, you will already have gotten it before.

Comment: @Hector I don't get any error with an up-to-date texliev 2022. Is your tex installation up to date? Did you try with the exact same code as in my answer?

Comment: I was not copying all your MWE into my real document. Problem solved and answer accepted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hector You're welcome!